# jquery mobile with php

Tags: php, iphone

I have two questions about jquery mobile:
1) If I put some php code in a jquery mobile app, and then put that in my iPhone, will it work?
2) If the above is true, how can a php code works if it is a server-side language?

Comment: jQuery can be used to send asynchronous calls to a PHP script. And it's going to take more than mobile jQuery to make an iPhone app. (I believe objective C is the app language?) I want to say jQuery mobile is for websites that have mobile versions to make it clean and fast for mobile browsers

Comment: Just as long as your file extensions are `.php` or you configure your server to [**run other file extensions AS PHP**](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm?rd=1), you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a mobile website and an iOS app. An iOS app is an application that one can install on an iPhone or iPad. A mobile website is simply a website which has a UI that is optimized to display well on a mobile device.

jQuery Mobile provides UI components for building mobile websites. The mobile website you build with jQuery Mobile will be viewable on an iPhone and (hopefully) will provide a better UX on the device compared to a website which is not optimized for mobile devices. However, jQuery Mobile will not make an iOS app that can be installed on your iPHone.

Comment: Is it possible to make my iPhone the localhost so I can store the mobile website for testing?

Comment: @Aldo I would use your PHP workstation as the localhost. If your workstation is connected to a wireless network you should be able to point your iPhone's browser to it using the workstation's IP address. Also, Apple's Xcode installs an iOS emulator which you can use to test your locally hosted code on a "virtual" iPhone or iPod.